# Create if logic with fields

Tags: entities, hooks

My task is to create a field that is visible to the author node.

Let's say the content type is "article" and the field is "textid" that contains the node ID number.

I've already created it with Display suite as a custom field with token [node:nid], so the result is some text with number of the node ID.

How can I make that field visible only by the node author?

What hook should I use?

Comment: Visible for edit or on the node view page?

Comment: On the node view page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [Field Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module:

> Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on who the entity owner 
>   is.

This seems to be exactly what you need.

To have real field (not display suite element), you can use [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) - more complicated than Display Suite, true, but at the same time more versatile and integrates well with everything field-related.

On the other hand, you can forget all these modules, and in your `node.tpl.php` simply compare current user id with node author's id, and if they are equal, print your data.

Comment: I had just copied the link to the module ready to paste into this exact same answer ;-). +1 for Field Permissions.

Comment: @Chapabu you beat me the same way couple of times, too :P OPs need was pretty popular and easy to answer, I guess.

Comment: Hmm, I have problem here. The field is created with Display suite/custom field and **Field Permission** module cannot set permission to it.

Comment: @user22957 oh, so it is not really a field in Drupal 7 meaning? Need a bit more time to think about it, then

Comment: @Molot The reason that I've used Display suite/custom fields is: The created field won't be visible for users to edit and also it has token support, so that field will show the node id.

Comment: @user22957 updated. Not so convenient as it should, but oh well.

Comment: If you know better approach for this, please let me know.

Comment: Molot, thank you for suggestion. I wish I could know more about coding...the **Computed field** module is very advanced and complicated. Is it possible to achieve this by creating a custom module and with hook_field_access somehow to set custom permission for this field?

Comment: @user22957 no, it isn't. If it would, Field Permissions module would work for you, as it is basically an UI for this very hook.

Comment: I've ended up by creating a field with FAPI from the UI, and set a default text and I'll remove the access in the form by hook_form_alter. The **field permission** module is working perfectly when the field is created by the FAPI UI. In future I guess it will be better not to use often this custom fields with Display suite 'cos it's very limited.